# create nested divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have to dinamically create nested divs using jquery .append()

But by this code:`

```
html=$("<div class='table'>")
    .append($("<div class='row'>"))
    .append($("<label>Denominazione Gruppo</label>"))
    .append($("<input type='text' id='denominazione'>"));
$("#content").empty();
$("#content").append(html);`
```

i get this wrong output

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row"></div>    //this closed tag should not be here!
        <label>Denominazione Gruppo</label>
        <input type="text" id="denominazione">
    </div>
</div>
```

Where i wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: `append()` does not work like string concatenation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to append the input and label to the `row` element

```
html = $("<div class='table'>").append($("<div class='row'>")
    .append("<label>Denominazione Gruppo</label>")
    .append("<input type='text' id='denominazione'>"));
$("#content").empty();
$("#content").append(html);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YcSkz/)

Comment: I know this is years late, but the .empty() and .append(html) can likely just be replaced with $('#content;).html(html) -- the .html() replaces all content within the selector

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.appendTo()` in this context.

Try,

```
 $("<label>Denominazione Gruppo</label>")
        .appendTo($("<div class='row'><input type='text' id='denominazione'>")
        .appendTo($("<div class='table'>")
        .appendTo($('#content'))));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/B4WBN/)

Comment: I also can't understand why this answer is down voted!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
html=$("<div class='table'>").append(
             $("<div class='row'>").append(
                  $("<label>Denominazione Gruppo</label>")).append(
                                   $("<input type='text' id='denominazione'>")));
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aWVw4/)